# Parse XML file and want required format By Awk Command Linux

Tags: xml, linux, awk, xml-parsing

I need some help, I have some xml request and I want to parse them.

```
[2016-03-08 00:00:01,000][http-nio-00.000.00.0-0000-exec-00] - <?xml version="1.0"?><COMMAND><TYPE>CBRSRESP</TYPE><TXNID>AN160308.0000.S12547</TXNID><TXNSTATUS>00018</TXNSTATUS><BALANCE></BALANCE><MESSAGE>LTRX FAIL</MESSAGE><FRBALANCE>0.0</FRBALANCE><TRID>2222277203602010000S46613</TRID><TXNMODE></TXNMODE></COMMAND>"
[2016-03-08 00:00:01,000][http-nio-00.000.00.0-0000-exec-00] - <COMMAND><TYPE>CBRSRESP</TYPE><TXNID>AN160308.0000.S12547</TXNID><TXNSTATUS>00018</TXNSTATUS><BALANCE></BALANCE><MESSAGE>LTRX FAIL</MESSAGE><FRBALANCE>0.0</FRBALANCE><TRID>2222277203602010000S46613</TRID><TXNMODE></TXNMODE></COMMAND>"
[2016-03-08 00:00:01,000][http-nio-00.000.00.0-0000-exec-00] - <?xml version="1.0"?><COMMAND><TYPE>CBRSRESP</TYPE><TXNSTATUS>00018</TXNSTATUS><TXNID>AN160308.0000.S12547</TXNID><BALANCE></BALANCE><MESSAGE>LTRX FAIL</MESSAGE><FRBALANCE>0.0</FRBALANCE><TRID>2222277203602010000S46613</TRID><TXNMODE></TXNMODE></COMMAND>"
```

I want parse these xml request as per below format.

```
TRID,TXNID,TXNSTATUS
```

eg .

```
2222277203602010000S46613,AN160308.0000.S12547,00018
2222277203602010000S46613,AN160308.0000.S12547,00018
2222277203602010000S46613,AN160308.0000.S12547,00018
```

Comment: Is this file copied from a windows machine? `^M`(CR) only for file formatted in windows?

Comment: Thanks for the Query. And No, This is copied from Linux Machine.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk:

```
awk '{print gensub(/.*<TRID>(.*)<\/TRID>.*/,"\\1","g")","gensub(/.*<TXNID>(.*)<\/TXNID>.*/,"\\1","g")","gensub(/.*<TXNSTATUS>(.*)<\/TXNSTATUS>.*/,"\\1","g")}' file
```

More about [gensub](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

Comment: Hi 7171, thanks for your response, I also have some log which don't have TXNID Parameter, In that cases, Shared answer print full line. :( 
eg.
TRID, [2016-03-08 00:01:16,075][http-nio-10.99.193.4-8081-exec-19] Full Log Row, TXNStatus Value

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way using GNU awk 4.* for `FPAT` that's easily extensible to print other fields in any order just be referencing them by name:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='<[^>]+>|[^<>]+' -v OFS=, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[$i]=$(i+1); print f["<TRID>"], f["<TXNID>"], f["<TXNSTATUS>"] }' file
2222277203602010000S46613,AN160308.0000.S12547,00018
2222277203602010000S46613,AN160308.0000.S12547,00018
2222277203602010000S46613,AN160308.0000.S12547,00018
```

If you want to handle some of the fields that can be empty (e.g. BALANCE) you just need the assignment to `f[<name>]` to be a ternary expression to check whether or not there is text before the next `<...>` string on the line:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='<[^>]+>|[^<>]+' -v OFS=, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[$i]=($(i+1)~/</?"":$(i+1)); print f["<TYPE>"], f["<BALANCE>"], f["<TXNID>"], f["<MESSAGE>"] }' file
CBRSRESP,,AN160308.0000.S12547,LTRX FAIL
CBRSRESP,,AN160308.0000.S12547,LTRX FAIL
CBRSRESP,,AN160308.0000.S12547,LTRX FAIL
```

Comment: Not Working for me....It's only show blank values.
$ awk -v FPAT='<[^>]+>|[^<>]+' -v OFS=, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[$i]=$(i+1); print f["<TRID>"], f["<TXNID>"], f["<TXNSTATUS>"] }' test4.as
,,
,,

Comment: Then your input file isn't as shown in your question or you aren't running GNU awk. What does `awk --version` tell you?

Comment: Hi Morton, I also tried to run shared command on the same sample file which i was provide but share command also not working on that.

Comment: I don't know what `run shared command` means. You didn't tell us what the output of `awk --version` is. And please stop posting answers - just edit your question to show whatever you want us to know, and format the code and input/output files using the editor `{}` button.

Comment: Hi Morton, Awk version is GNU Awk 3.1.7. And My mean to say awk command which you have posted, i also tried that awk command on the same xml format which i mention in my query.

Comment: You are running an extremely old version of gawk from before FPAT was introduced. You need version 4.0 or later. You are currently missing a **LOT** of extremely useful features (see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Feature-History).